# Similarity of Jordan Canonical Form

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $A\in \mathbb{F}^{n×n}$ such that $\sigma (A)=\lbrace 1\rbrace$, then $A$ is similar to $A^k$ for all positive integer $k$.
Show that the converse is not true.

My attempt: Let $A$ has JCF $J(1)$. I know that if $A$ has JCF $\oplus_{i=1}^mJ_{k_i}(\lambda)$ and $A$ is nonsingular, then the JCF of $A^2$ is $\oplus_{i=1}^mJ_{k_i}(\lambda^2)$. I can already see how the proof goes because their JCFs are equal since $\lambda=1$ but I can't connect how they are similar.
Also, I just need to give a counterexample to prove the converse is not true, right?

Any hint will do and is a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Two square matrices are similar iff their Jordan normal form coincide.